# How to fix "$("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip(); "

Tags: javascript, jquery

In one of the pages of my website, I see an error "$("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();" at the top of the browser. How to fix this?

Comment: Is this really PHP? Are there no other relevant tags?

Comment: "*My boss told me something. Can I sue him?*". Would you be able to answer that question? No? You probably need more details, right? We can't guess based on your question either. Define it better. What error? When? What line? Mind reading is 150£ an hour extra.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Why undersell yourself, this community could do with amazing mind readers.

Answer (score 2):

You could make sure it's wrapped inside a `<script>` tag.